# Angular 2 CLI Jasmine unit test fails when using beforeAll instead of beforeEach

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, angular-cli, angular2-testing

I created a new project with NG-CLI (beta.15) and modified the `app.component.spec` to change the `beforeEach` to to a `beforeAll` and it caused the tests to fail with the following error:

> Failed: Cannot create the component AppComponent as it was not imported into the testing module!

I don't understand what this error means and of course why I would get it in the first place.

Here's the modified spec:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('App: Ng2CliTest2', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');
  }));

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('app works!');
  }));
});
```

I then modified the spec to this and the first two tests pass and the third fails with the following message :

> Failed: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

let fixture;
let app;

describe('App: Ng2CliTest2', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;        
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');
  }));

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('app works!');
  }));
});
```

I don't understand why there are any failures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without knowing it, Angular actually [resets the testing module](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/core/testing/test_bed.ts#L196) in it's own undercover `beforeEach` ([see `testing.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/core/testing/testing.ts#L23))

```
var _global = <any>(typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window);

// Reset the test providers and the fake async zone before each test.
if (_global.beforeEach) {
  _global.beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    resetFakeAsyncZone();
  });
}
```

I haven't even tried this, but it you want to know how it works to maybe try and (safely) disable this feature, this is what I've figured out:

Somewhere in your configuration you have imported

```
@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js
```

This is many times in a `karma-test-shim.js` file. This file contains pretty much all the testing utilities we use in a Angular test. It's pretty much a compilation of everything exported from the [testing module](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/core/testing/index.ts). This include the above testing file that adds a global `beforeEach` call.

And just if it's not obvious from the above information your `beforeAll` is only good for the first test, then Angular resets the test bed. So the next test you are trying to create a component from an empty test bed configuration.

Answer (score 1):

For whoever is looking for a way to actually prevent angular from resetting the testbed: [see this article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-initialize-your-tests-in-a-beforeall-21e709474632)

Relevant part:

```
import { TestBed, TestModuleMetadata } from '@angular/core/testing';
const resetTestingModule = TestBed.resetTestingModule;
const preventAngularFromResetting = () => TestBed.resetTestingModule = () => TestBed;
const allowAngularToReset = () => {
  resetTestingModule();
  TestBed.resetTestingModule = resetTestingModule;
};
export const setUpTestBed = (moduleDef: TestModuleMetadata, ...funcs: (() => void)[]) => {
  beforeAll(done => (async () => {
    resetTestingModule();
    preventAngularFromResetting();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule(moduleDef);
    funcs.forEach(func => func());

    TestBed.resetTestingModule = () => TestBed;
    return await TestBed.compileComponents();
  })().then(done).catch(done.fail));

  afterAll(() => allowAngularToReset());
};
```